# Complie Error: could not convert

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am trying to put a specific amount of movies the user enters to the array.
Then I am going to use a pointer of arrays of class in a function as will be shown below

When I compile my program, it gives me an error message saying
"could not convert ' (MovieData**) (& pMovie)' from 'MovieData**' to MovieData'

My body

```
int amount = 0;
cout << "How many movies did you watch last month?";
cin >> amount;

MovieData *pMovie[amount];
*pMovie = new MovieData[amount];

cout << "Please enter the information of your Movies!" << endl;
readMovieData(pMovie, amount);         //This line!

cout << "Here are the information with your Movies!" << endl;
MovieDatastats(pMovie, amount);        //This line!
```

and here are my functions

```
void readMovieData(MovieData *pMovie, int const size)
{
string title;
string director;
int year;
int time;

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter the Title of the movie.";
    getline(cin,title);
    pMovie[i].setTitle(title);

    cout << "\nPlease enter the Director name of the movie.";
    getline(cin,director);
    pMovie[i].setDirector(director);

    cout << "\nPlease enter the year it was released.";
    cin >> year;
        if(year >= 1900 && year <= 2004)
            pMovie[i].setYear(year);
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter a year between 1900 and 2004." << endl;
            year = 0;
        }

    cout << "\nPlease enter the time the movie last.";
    cin >> time;
        if(time > 0 && time < 14400)
            pMovie[i].setTime(time);
        else
        {
            time = 0;
            cout << "Please enter a time between 0 and 14400 in minutes." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

that is for my function to set the information into the private class

and another function which is to play around with the information of the private class

```
void MovieDatastats(MovieData *pMovie, int const size)
{
float sumTime = 0.0;
float averageTime = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sumTime +=pMovie[i].getTime();
}
averageTime = sumTime/size;

cout << "Your average time of all your movie is: " << averageTime << endl;

int oldYear = 0;
int count = 0;
int recentYear = 0;
int counter = 0;

oldYear = pMovie[0].getYear();
recentYear = pMovie[0].getYear();

for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
{
    if(pMovie[j].getYear() < oldYear)
    {
        oldYear = pMovie[j].getYear();
        count = j;
    }
    else if(pMovie[j].getYear() > recentYear)
    {
        recentYear = pMovie[j].getYear();
        counter = j;
    }
}

cout << "The oldest Movie you have watched is called..." << endl;
cout << "Title: " << pMovie[count].getTitle() << endl;
cout << "Director: " << pMovie[count].getDirector() << endl;
cout << "Release Year: " << pMovie[count].getYear() << endl;

cout << "The most newest Movie you have watched is called..." << endl;
cout << "Title: " << pMovie[counter].getTitle() << endl;
cout << "Director: " << pMovie[counter].getDirector() << endl;
cout << "Release Year: " << pMovie[counter].getYear() << endl;
}
```

Also, how do I delete the allocated memory and set the pointer to point at NULL?

Comment: 1) You need to tell us which line causes the error. 2) They don't teach std::vector?  With std::vector, there is no issue with when or where to delete allocated memory.

Comment: You seem to be making an array of pointers and then only using the first.

Comment: @user3345335 - If the answers give you what you're looking for, please give credit by upvoting them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
MovieData *pMovie[amount];
*pMovie = new MovieData[amount];
```

The first line declares an array of Movie data pointers.  You don't want that -- what you want is a pointer to MovieData.  Thus, the second line is also wrong.  Here is the correction:

```
MovieData *pMovie;
pMovie = new MovieData[amount];
```

As to when to deallocate, this is the danger of using code like above.  You deallocate when you no longer need pMovie.  But when that time is when you no longer need it is the reason why memory checkers exist -- it is so easy to make a mistake.  That's why vectors are so convenient:

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<MovieData> pMovie(amount);
```

That's it.  No need to deallocate anything.  Now, to interface this with your existing functions, pass the address of the first element in the vector:

```
readMovieData(&pMovie[0], pMovie.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MovieData *pMovie[amount];
```

and

```
MovieData *pMovie
```

are two different types.  The first is an array with elements of type `MovieData *` while the second is a scalar type, that is a pointer to MovieData.

You declared functions readMovieData and MovieDatastats the following way

```
void readMovieData(MovieData *pMovie, int const size);
void MovieDatastats(MovieData *pMovie, int const size);
```

with the first parameter of type

```
MovieData *pMovie
```

However when you call these functions

```
readMovieData(pMovie, amount);

MovieDatastats(pMovie, amount);
```

you pass as the argument

```
MovieData *pMovie[amount];
```

The compiler can not implicitly convert MovieData *pMovie[amount]; to MovieData *pMovie.

The functions should be declared as

```
void readMovieData(MovieData **pMovie, int const size);
void MovieDatastats(MovieData **pMovie, int const size);
```

Correspondingly you need to change bodies of the functions.

Or you could have the functions as you declared them but pass to them as the argument

```
*pMovie
```

that is the first element of the array.

For example

```
void readMovieData(MovieData *pMovie, int const size);
void MovieDatastats(MovieData *pMovie, int const size);
//...

readMovieData(*pMovie, amount);

MovieDatastats(*pMovie, amount);
```